# Почему возникает ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Ошибка возникает при указании ресурса с ViewModel моего класса:

```
<Window x:Class="KTM.TouristsListWnd"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:KTM"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TouristsList" Height="388.102" Width="1001.393" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.DataContext>
         <!-- ошибка воникает здесь -->
        <local:TouristsListViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

не смотря на то что класс находится в области видимости (public)?

```cs
public class TouristsListViewModel
```

UPD: конструктор класса:

```
public TouristsListViewModel()
{
    try {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tourmanager.tourists;", conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
            _tourists.Add(new Tourist((int)dr["id"], (string)dr["firstname"], (string)dr["secondname"],
                (string)dr["patronymic"], (string)dr["passport"], (string)dr["sex"]));
        }
    } catch (MySqlException ex) {
        throw new Exception("", ex);
    } finally {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: А какая ошибка? И компилируется ли ваш проект _без_ этого?

Comment: @VladD да компилируется, ошибка прям дословно "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта”. Просто мозолит глаза, не могу понять в чем загвоздка. Ссылка на скриншот: https://yadi.sk/i/7plMWxYD34KmPn

Comment: А если сказать проекту Rebuild? Что показывает в окне Output?

Comment: @VladD Успешно 1, с ошибками и пропущено - 0. Без ошибок собирается.

Comment: Ну так тогда ошибка должна уйти. Гляньте!

Comment: @VladD да вот нет, ошибка осталась. Она не мешает собираться решению, но сильно мозолит глаза... Если найду решение то отпишусь здесь

Comment: Ошибка есть даже сразу после пересборки?

Comment: Да, а покажите ваш конструктор в классе `TouristsListViewModel`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50492/discussion-between-demol0cv-and-vladd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём. Программа нормально компилируется, а в Intellisense (то есть, в визуальном редакторе) возникает ошибка.

Редактор XAML пытается создать экземпляр `TouristsListWnd`, чтобы нарисовать его. При этом он, понятно, пытается создать и экземпляр `TouristsListViewModel`, потому что это часть XAML. Но в design-time конструктор, судя по всему, не срабатывает.

Простое решение — проверять, не бежим ли мы в дизайнере. Для этого можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
    return;
```

в начале конструктора.

---

Дополнение: заметьте, что объявление свойств с их инициализацией наподобие

```
public MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].Conne‌​ctionString);
```

тоже по факту является частью конструктора, и если мы отключаем это в дизайнере, нужно перенести эту инициализацию в точку после проверки. Получится вот что:

```
public MySqlConnection conn;

public TouristsListViewModel()
{
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
        return;
    conn = new MySqlConnection(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].Conne‌​ctionString);
    ...
}
```

---

Заметьте, что нехорошо в конструкторе VM-объекта проводить длинную операцию — это затормозит UI-поток. Поэтому попробуем вынести чтение таблицы в отдельный поток. Получится что-то такое:

```
public TouristsListViewModel()
{
    LoadData();
}

async void LoadData()
{
    InfoLabel.Text = "Loading database...";
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => LoadDataInBackground());
        InfoLabel.Text = null;
    }
    catch(MySqlException ex)
    {
        InfoLabel.Text = "Loading failed, error: " + ex.Message;
    }
}

void LoadDataInBackground()
{
    try {
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tourmanager.tourists;", conn);
        MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
            _tourists.Add(
                new Tourist((int)dr["id"], (string)dr["firstname"],
                            (string)dr["secondname"], (string)dr["patronymic"],
                            (string)dr["passport"], (string)dr["sex"]));
        }
    } finally {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю от себя(еще более простым языком на мой взгляд). Данная ошибка возникает, если в конструкторе VM у вас создается объект на основании запроса в БД(этот запрос или объект для запроса -  формируется через класс ConfigurationManager). Чтобы ошибки не было - нужно все обращения в БД скрыть за условие, которое указал автор:

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
{
     return;
}
else
{
     / *Здесь код обращения к БД */
}
```

Вместо данных из БД я в инициализаторе объекта ввел вручную в нужное поле(или свойство) какое-то значение, этого должно хватить для удобной отрисовки дизайна в xaml.